# In Vim, is it possible to open a file in specify opened split window?

Tags: vim, editor

Recently, I use Vim as my editor while programming Ruby, but I don't know if I can do that in Vim. Let's say in my Vim, I already have 2 vertical split windows named `A` and `B` like this:

[image: split window]

And then I hit `gf` to jump to the source file `xyz.rb` if I park the cursor under the `require` statement, but it will show in the same window `A` by default.

Is there any shortcuts or quick combo that I can open or show the source file `xyz.rb` in the opened `B` split window? (and even if the window `B` doesn't exist yet, create one automatically)

I've check the manual, and it does has some ways to show `xyz.rb` in different horizontal split window or a new tab, but is it possible if I want to show it in specify opened split window `B`.

thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functionality you describe is already present in the form of a 'preview window'.

You could map a key (e.g. <kbd>gf</kbd>) to something like

```
:exec 'pedit ' . expand('<cfile>')
```

This will open the filename under the cursor in the *preview* window. A new preview window will be opened if none exists. See **[`:he preview-window`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#preview-window)** for more information.

Use <kbd>^W</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> (or `:pclose`) to close the preview window

Comment: thanks for your reply, but the preview window might be a little different from what I want. first, I need the opened file would be editable, not just preview. and second, I want the file opened in the specify split window which is already exist, like the window B in the above picture. :)

Comment: @高見龍 in what way? Perhaps I can help you find what you want

Comment: actually, I am not sure is that possible to do that :P

Comment: Well, I'm sure it isn't possible unless you tell me what you need/what you don't like about the preview window

Comment: Thanks again, my actually need is while I'm editing a source file named A, and sometimes I want to edit the source file B which is required by file A. I used to hit `gf` to jump to the file and jump back by `ctrl+^`, but since I have a wide monitor, why not just show the source file B in the right side split window? But sometimes the right side split window already open the other file, just like the attached image above. So, my question is: is there any way to open the file B in some split window which already exist, and not just preview, I might need it to be editable :)

Comment: sorry I'm not native English, please bear my poor grammar :P

Comment: actually I can do that with several steps, such as `:vs` to open a new vertical window if the split window doesn't exist, and then hit `gf` to show the file. I'm just curious is there any easy way to do that :)

Comment: @高見龍 Erm, Preview window is editable just fine. You could look at `:se splitright` with `^Wf`. Also the `switchbuf` option might interest you. Also consider `:vert pedit`